# How to run .net core in docker on arch linux

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core

`docker run -it microsoft/dotnet:latest` when i run this, it change to root in the container like this `root@7b41fcb12add` and `7b41fcb12add` is container id

After this everything i do will disappear when I type `exit` to exit the container

The command I get from [.net site](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#dockercmd)

How do I use .net core in docker ?

Comment: you should read https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/

Comment: Your question is not very clear for me. What is your specific goal?

Comment: I dont udnerstand. Are you closing docker by `ctrl + c` or just .Net Core App?

Comment: @J.Doe ak sorry i mean type `exit` command to exit the container

Comment: @user2915097 thank you I am reading it now